# Site Visitors SP 2007

Tags: document, library

How can I place documents in a document library and all Site Visitors to only save the document to their own local drive?

Comment: If the users are members/owners - This can be a good starting point to save the documents in the local drive http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/sharepointecm/thread/4e43e1fe-f58d-41c2-bbc0-07df59844258

Answer (score 1):

Users with read only access to a library can open documents but can't save them back to the library.